# VBA: sorted collection

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, collections

The code below extracts & format values from the range B6:E6, and then stores them in the variable. Afterwards, the routine sorts the collection of 4 variables in the ascending order. When sorted they're being put into the range L31:O31.

The problem is that if there are less **than 4 variables** selected, say 3, the routine will skip L31 cell, and put the rest to M31:O31. Whilst it should be input as L31:N31, and O31 - blank.

How can the code be modified to make it fulfill the data starting from L31 if less than 4 variables are in the collection?

```
Function ExtractKey(s As Variant) As Long
   Dim v As Variant, n As Long
    v = Trim(s) 'remove spaces leave only spaces between words
       If v Like "*(*)" Then 'if it's SOPXX (YYYY) then
          n = Len(v) 'find number of the characters
            If n = 11 Then
               v = Mid(v, n - 7, 7) 'find the number of SOP + year in  bracket
            ElseIf n = 12 Then
               v = Mid(v, n - 8, 8)
            End If
            v = Replace(v, "(", "") 'replace the brackets with nothing
            v = Replace(v, " ", "")

            'SOP10 (2015) doesn't have to go first before SOP12 (2014); switch figures
            If n = 11 Then
               v = Right(v, 4) + Left(v, 1)
            ElseIf n = 12 Then
               v = Right(v, 4) + Left(v, 2)
            End If

        ExtractKey = CLng(v)
     Else
        ExtractKey = 0
     End If
End Function

Sub Worksheet_Delta_Update()
   Dim SourceRange As Range, TargetRange As Range
   Dim i As Long, j As Long, minKey As Long, minAt As Long
   Dim v As Variant
   Dim C As New Collection

   Set SourceRange = Worksheets("t").Range("B6:E6")
   Set TargetRange = Worksheets("x").Range("L31:O31")

    For i = 1 To 4
       v = SourceRange.Cells(1, i).Value
       C.Add Array(ExtractKey(v), v)
    Next i

   'transfer data
    For i = 1 To 4
       minAt = -1
       For j = 1 To C.Count
           If minAt = -1 Or C(j)(0) < minKey Then
             minKey = C(j)(0)
             minAt = j
           End If
       Next j
      TargetRange.Cells(1, i).Value = C(minAt)(1)
      C.Remove minAt
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you post data from the ranges for a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? If we can reproduce then we can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add one variable e.g. `col` which will be used instead of variable `i` when the value is inserted into `TargetRange`. This variable will work the same way as the `i` works but it will be incremented only when the value which is inserted is not empty. HTH

```
   'transfer data
   Dim col As Integer
   col = 1
    For i = 1 To 4
       minAt = -1
       For j = 1 To C.Count
           If minAt = -1 Or C(j)(0) < minKey Then
             minKey = C(j)(0)
             minAt = j
           End If
       Next j
       If (C(minAt)(1) <> "") Then
            TargetRange.Cells(1, col).Value = C(minAt)(1)
            col = col + 1
        End If
      C.Remove minAt
    Next i
```

Comment: Yes, awesome, it works! Thanks! Added slight modificaiton: `TargetRange.ClearContents` since the range remains fulfilled with the values from previous selection :)

Comment: You are welcome! Yes thats right, the target range needs to be cleared from the previous values.